# Examples of the Gysin Maps for Hodge Cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to learn about Gysin maps on Hodge cohomology, as defined in the Stacks project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0G8A).  Namely, if $X \to S$ is a morphism of schemes and $Z \to X$ is a closed immersion of finite presentation whose conormal sheaf is locally free of rank $c$ satisfying additional regularity properties (e.g. locally being cut out by a Koszul regular sequence), then we get maps
$$ \gamma^{p, q}: H^q(Z, \Omega^p_{Z/S}) \to H^{q + c}(X, \Omega^{p+c}_{X/S})$$
which are useful in defining cycle classes in Hodge cohomology.

1. The definition of $\gamma^{p,q}$ given in the link above is somewhat opaque to me; is there a more "down-to-earth" way to understand the construction of the maps $\gamma^{p, q}$ (perhaps with simplifying assumptions on $Z$ and $X$)?
2. Are there computable explicit examples of the $\gamma^{p,q}$ that help illustrate what is really going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one case where it's easy to understand: Suppose that $X\to S$ is smooth and proper, and $Z\subset X$ is a smooth *divisor*, so $c=1$. Then Gysin is just the connecting map associated to the Poincaré residue sequence
$$0\to \Omega_{X/S}^{p+1}\to \Omega_{X/S}^{p+1}(\log Z)\to \Omega_{Z/S}^p\to 0$$
Of course, you can iterate this if $Z$ is a global complete intersection. But  I'm not sure if it can  be made so concrete in a completely general situation.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!  So for instance (analytically) when X is a curve and Z is a point, then this map would send $1 \in H^0(Z, \Omega_Z^0)$ to a $(1, 1)$ form in a small punctured neighborhood of Z which has residue 1 at Z (i.e. $dx/x$ where $x$ is a local coordinate around $Z$)?  In general, is this connecting map related to wedging with the logarithmic derivatives of local equations cutting out $Z$?